# member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' (solution.cpp) | UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

*I was practicing a question on based on singly linked list which seemed to be pretty simple. The question was to return true if the given singly linked list is a palindrome or else return false .*
I first got the length the of the list by traversing till the last node then pushed all the values of the list to a vector, then checked if the vector is same if traversed from the last if same return true or return false.

But I got this error saying that:

> Line 24: Char 24: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:33:24

```
class Solution {
    public:
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
        struct ListNode *temp;
        int j,data,l=0,r;
        vector <int> v;
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL){//to get length of the linked list
            j++;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp=head;
        for(int i=0;i<j;++i){
            data=temp->val;
            v.push_back(data);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        r=v.size()-1;
        while (l<=r){
            if(v[l]!=v[r]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
        
        
};
```

Comment: What happens if `head` is a null pointer? And does this so-called "competition" or "judge" site provide the test-case used? Then you could build a [mre] to *debug* on your own system.

Comment: Assuming `l<=r` is true and you enter that last loop, when do you suppose it becomes false?

Comment: Btw, you never initialized `j` from the outset, so `j++` is already UB. If you were using a reasonable compiler with reasonable warnings it should tell you as much.

Comment: Side note: How about _not_ traversing the list twice for no good reason? Also, you increment an uninitialized `j` in the first loop, which may have ~whatever value and may also be 0 by chance, which makes debugging tricky.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek can you suggest me a better way to solve to tackle this question??          ps: I got that I missed to initialize j :/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you brief more about what you are saying?

Comment: @molbdnilo I assumed that it will become false if the char from the last does not match the char from first then it becomes true then the same goes to second char and second last char and then so on.......

Comment: @Ragesh Does `v[l]!=v[r]` or `return false` (that's all you're doing in the loop) modify `l` or `r`?

Comment: What do you know about pointers and null pointers? What does your text-books or tutorials or teachers say about pointer and null pointers? I really hope you're not using whatever site you're using as a way to learn programming and C++, because no so-called "competition" or "judge" site is meant to be a learning or teaching resource. You need to learn properly before using such sites, and that includes things like pointers.

Comment: Tags are for what a question is about, not for what it contains.

Comment: @Ragesh Yes. Do not traverse the list twice, ever.

Comment: "based on singly linked list" There is nothing unique to lists here. You could have done the exact same thing traversing a stream or another vector or any other sequential container.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution to your question. Try this and let me know:

```
class Solution {
    public:
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head || !head->next) {
            return true; // empty list or single node list is a palindrome
        }
        // Find the middle of the linked list using slow and fast pointers
        ListNode *slow = head, *fast = head;
        while (fast->next && fast->next->next) {
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next->next;
        }
        // Reverse the second half of the linked list
        ListNode *prev = nullptr, *curr = slow->next;
        while (curr) {
            ListNode *next = curr->next;
            curr->next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        // Check if the first and second half of the linked list are identical
        ListNode *p1 = head, *p2 = prev;
        while (p2) {
            if (p1->val != p2->val) {
                return false;
            }
            p1 = p1->next;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        // Reconstruct the linked list by reversing the second half back
        // to its original order before returning
        curr = prev;
        prev = nullptr;
        while (curr) {
            ListNode *next = curr->next;
            curr->next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        slow->next = prev;
        return true;
    }
};
```